# appending cloned template is still of type fragment

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I seem to be having an issue with the cloning a template's content and appending it. I always thought when you append a document.fragment it would convert itself to a node.

If you check the example below, you'll see that the clone variable after it has been appended still doesn't have a parentNode.

```js
(function() {
  var template = document.getElementById('template'),
    wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper'),
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    rows = {};
    
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    body.appendChild(clone);
    rows[i] = clone;
    
    console.log(clone.parentNode);
  }
    
})();
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>

<template id="template">
  <div class="row">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Am I missing something?

---

EDIT:
K after some reading on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment I came across this:

> ... append or insert the fragment into the DOM using Node interface
>   methods such as appendChild() or insertBefore(). Doing this moves the
>   fragment's nodes into the DOM, **leaving behind an empty**
>   DocumentFragment.

So how do we keep track of the cloned element as a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct what you've found in the docs. The `node` variable still refers to the `DocumentFragment`. 
What you have to do is query the parent element's children.

Your code will look like this:

```js
(function() {
  var template = document.getElementById('template'),
    wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper'),
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    rows = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    body.appendChild(clone);
    rows[i] = clone;
  }

  // find all elements with the class 'row' assigned
  // in other words: find all cloned nodes
  console.log(body.querySelectorAll('.row'));

})();
```

Comment: Eventually I assigned a unique classname and I used that to select the div and push it to the rows object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelector()` on clone to get the `.row` element and insert that instead

```js
(function() {
  var template = document.getElementById('template'),
    wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true),    
    div = clone.querySelector('.row');
    
    div.addEventListener('click', function(){
       console.log('click')
       console.log(this.parentNode)
    })
    
    wrapper.appendChild(div);
     
  }
    
})();
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>

<template id="template">
  <div class="row">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</template>
```